# ¿Cómo mantener clases agregadas al hacer click en un boton con texto Anterior ? - Javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
window.onload = ()=>{

  let box = document.getElementsByClassName("questionnaire"),
  information = document.getElementsByClassName("information"),
  countReplys = document.createElement("span"),
  h1 = information[0].getElementsByTagName("h1"),
  div = information[0].getElementsByTagName("div"),
  buttonNext = document.createElement("button"),
  buttonPrevious = document.createElement("button"),
  loading = document.createElement("span"),
  soundCheck = new Audio(),
  soundWrongError = new Audio(),
  soundNext = new Audio();
  
soundNext.src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/crw7azchg5esrju/1606494046260.mp3?dl=1";
  
soundCheck.src = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/x53ogvikk0iqkdk/sound-effect-check.mp3?dl=1";
  
soundWrongError.src = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/tsj4v0q26oazakf/sound-effect-wrong-answer.mp3?dl=1";

loading.id = "loading";
countReplys.id = "count-reply";
h1[0].setAttribute("style", "margin-top: 5%");
  
  var i, puntaje, selectAnAnswer, status, j = true;

  const backupTest = information[0].innerHTML;

class questionnaire{
  constructor(){

    this.preguntas = [
      "¿Cuánto es el diámetro del Universo?",
      "¿Qué es una protogalaxia?",
      "¿Cuántas y cuáles son los tipos de galaxia"
    ]

    this.respuestas = {
    0: [
        "a) Al menos 93 000 millones de años luz.",
        "b) Al menos 231 050 millones de años luz.",
        "c) Al menos 129 500 millones de años luz.",
        "d) Al menos 54 000 millones de años luz."
    ],
    1: [
        "a) Es una mínima porción de una galaxia.",
        "b) Es un tipo de galaxia de la secuencia de Hubble.",
        "c)  Es una nube de gas que se forma en una galaxia.",
        "d) Ninguna de las anteriores es correcta."
    ],
    2: [
        "a) Existen 4 y son elípticas, espirales, regulares e irregulares.",
        "b) Existen 3 y son elípticas, espirales e irregulares.",
        "c) Existen 9 y son elípticas, espirales, lenticulares, irregulares, activas, seyfert, starburst, cuásares y radiogalaxias.",
        "d) Todas las anteriores son correctas."
    ], 
  }
    this.respuestasCorrectas = [
      "a)",
      "c)",
      "c)"
    ]

    this.mostrarResultados = 
    `
    <div class="results">¡Has acabado de resolver este test de ${this.preguntas.length} preguntas! Para ver los resultados por favor haga click en el boton de abajo:<br>
    <button style="float: none;">Mostrar resultados</button></div>
    `
    
  }

  addNewText(title, answers){ 

  if (i === 0) information[0].prepend(countReplys);
  
  title.textContent = `${this.preguntas[i]}`;
  
  answers.innerHTML = `
  <div class="reply r${i}">${this.respuestas[i][0]}</div>
  <div class="reply r${i}">${this.respuestas[i][1]}</div>
  <div class="reply r${i}">${this.respuestas[i][2]}</div>
  <div class="reply r${i}">${this.respuestas[i][3]}</div>
  `;

  let replysQuestionnary = document.querySelectorAll(`.r${i}`);

  replysQuestionnary.forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener("click", e=> {

    let targetReplys = e.target;
    selectAnAnswer = true;

  if (status === true){
    if (targetReplys.textContent.includes(this.respuestasCorrectas[i])){
      targetReplys.classList.add("check");
      puntaje += 7;
      soundCheck.play();
    } else {
      targetReplys.classList.add("danger");
      soundWrongError.play();
      puntaje += 0;
      for (let replyCorrect of replysQuestionnary){
        if (replyCorrect.textContent.includes(this.respuestasCorrectas[i])){
        replyCorrect.classList.add("check");
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    return;
  }

  status = false;

  });
});

  }

  mostrarResultado(){

  this.mensajeResultado = document.createElement("div");
  let questionAgainTest = document.createElement("span"),
  allQuestions = this.preguntas.length,

  // Mensajes al usuario
  messageForAllReplyCorrect = document.createTextNode("¡Felicidades has acertado todas las respuestas! ,sabes mucho acerca del Universo, deberías ser Astrónomo/a."),

  messageFor99ReplyCorrect = document.createTextNode("¡Casii! Te ha faltado un poco para acertar todas las respuesta. Realmente eres muy bueno/a en esto."),

  messageFor75ReplyCorrect = document.createTextNode("¡WoW! Has superado el 50% de respuestas correctas, eres muy inteligente no lo olvides."),

  messageFor50ReplyCorrect = document.createTextNode("¡Nada mal! , has acertado aproximadamente el 50% de respuestas correctas, sigue así, este no es el final, lo puedes intentar varias veces."),

  messageFor25ReplyCorrect = document.createTextNode("¡Tu puntaje es realmente bajo! ,tal vez las preguntas han estado un poco dificiles, ¿Te animas a volver a responder el test?."),

  messageForNoneReplyCorrect = document.createTextNode("¡Qué mal! ,no acertaste ninguna respuesta, pero no te preocupes lo puedes volver a intentar.");

  this.mensajeResultado.id = "result";
  
  this.mensajeResultado.innerHTML = `<br><br>Tu puntaje es ${puntaje} de un total de ${this.preguntas.length} preguntas. Por cada respuesta correcta obtuviste 7 pts, muchas gracias por responder este test.`

  if (puntaje === allQuestions){
  this.mensajeResultado.prepend(messageForAllReplyCorrect);
  }
  else if (puntaje <= allQuestions*(99/100) || puntaje > allQuestions*(75/100)){
  this.mensajeResultado.prepend(messageFor99ReplyCorrect);
  }
  else if (puntaje <= allQuestions*(75/100) || puntaje > allQuestions*(50/100)){
  this.mensajeResultado.prepend(messageFor75ReplyCorrect);
  }
  else if (puntaje <= allQuestions*(50/100) || puntaje > allQuestions*(25/100)){
  this.mensajeResultado.prepend(messageFor50ReplyCorrect);
  }
  else if (puntaje <= allQuestions*(25/100) || puntaje > 0){
  this.mensajeResultado.prepend(messageFor25ReplyCorrect);
  }
  else if (puntaje === 0) { 
  this.mensajeResultado.prepend(messageForNoneReplyCorrect);
  }

  questionAgainTest.innerHTML = ` ¿Desea volver a realizar este test? <span id="yes">Si</span> o <span id="no">No</span>`

  this.mensajeResultado.appendChild(questionAgainTest);
   
  return this.mensajeResultado;

  }
  
  againTest(){
  setTimeout(()=>{
  information[0].innerHTML = "";
  information[0].appendChild(loading);
  information[0].classList.add("padding");
    setTimeout(()=>{
    loading.remove();
    information[0].classList.remove("padding");
    information[0].innerHTML = backupTest;   
    }, 5000);
  }, 3000);
  }

  finishTest(){
  let result = document.getElementById("result");
  result.firstElementChild.remove();
  result.innerHTML += `<br><br>Muchas gracias, que tenga un buen día o buenas noches, le deseo una Feliz Navidad y prospero Año Nuevo.`
  }

}

  /* <------------ Objeto ------------> */
  const testUniverse = new questionnaire(),
        preguntasAll = testUniverse.preguntas.length;

  /* <------------ Botones ------------> */
  buttonNext.textContent = "Siguiente";
  buttonNext.className = "next";
  
  buttonPrevious.textContent = "Anterior";
  buttonPrevious.className = "previous";

  box[0].addEventListener('click', e=>{
    let target = e.target;
    
    if (target.tagName === "BUTTON"){
    
    soundNext.play();

      if (target.textContent === "Mostrar resultados"){ 
      if (j === true) information[0].appendChild(testUniverse.mostrarResultado());
      return j = false;
      }

      setTimeout(()=>{
      target.remove();
      if (i == 1) information[0].appendChild(buttonPrevious);
      information[0].appendChild(buttonNext);
      }, 3000);

      if (target.className === "start-test"){
      i = 0;
      selectAnAnswer = false;
      j = true;
      puntaje = 0;
      status = true;
      setTimeout(()=>{
      h1[0].removeAttribute("style");
      }, 3000);    
      }

      else if (target.className === "next"){

      if (selectAnAnswer === false){
      return Swal.fire({
        text: "Por favor seleccione una respuesta...",
        icon: "warning",
        iconColor: "#CB4040",
        confirmButtonColor: "#CB4040"
      });
      }
      else {
        ++i;
        status = true;       
      }

      selectAnAnswer = false;

    }
      else if (target.className === "previous"){
        --i;
      }

      fadeOut(information[0]);
      fadeIn(information[0]); 

      setTimeout(()=>{
        if (i <= preguntasAll - 1){
        status = true;
        countReplys.textContent = `Pregunta ${i+1} de ${preguntasAll}:`;
        return testUniverse.addNewText(h1[0], div[0]);
        } else {
        return information[0].innerHTML = testUniverse.mostrarResultados;
        }
      }, 3000);
  }
  
  else if (target.id === "yes"){
    fadeOut(information[0]);
    fadeIn(information[0]);
    h1[0].setAttribute("style", "margin-top: 5%");
    return testUniverse.againTest();
  }
  else if (target.id === "no"){
    testUniverse.finishTest();
  }
  
 });

const fadeIn = selector =>{
  setTimeout(()=>{
  selector.classList.add("fade-in");
  selector.classList.remove("fade-out");
  }, 3000);
}
const fadeOut = selector =>{   
  status = false;
  selector.classList.add("fade-out");
  selector.classList.remove("fade-in"); 
}

setTimeout(()=>{
  Swal.fire({
    icon: "warning",
    iconColor: "#CB4040",
    text: 'Porfavor no haga trampa, responda honestamente sin buscar información en el navegador o ayuda externa.',
    confirmButtonColor: "#CB4040",
    showClass: {
      popup: 'animate__animated animate__fadeInDown'
    },
    hideClass: {
      popup: 'animate__animated animate__fadeOutUp'
    }
  })
}, 4000);
 
}
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
  padding: 8% 0;
}

main {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  z-index: 10;
}
main .questionnaire {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 0 3% 3%;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 20px 20px 20px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), -20px -26px 20px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
main .questionnaire h1 {
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 4.5em;
  font-family: "Electrolize";
  margin-top: 3%;
}
main .questionnaire .information {
  position: relative;
}
main .questionnaire .information > div,
#count-reply{
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: "Andika New Basic";
}
main .questionnaire button {
  padding: 12px 100px;
  float: right;
  font-size: 16.5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
  background: black;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) 12%, #757909 53%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) 93%);
  font-family: "Architects Daughter", sans-serif;
  box-shadow: 0 7px 10px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  color: azure;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
main .questionnaire button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
main .questionnaire button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
main .questionnaire button:active {
  transform: scale(0.85);
}
main .questionnaire .previous {
  float: left;
}
.padding{
  padding: 25%;
}
#count-reply{
  margin-top: 1.5%;
  display: block;
  font-style: italic;
  padding-bottom: .5%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.fade-in {
  animation: fadein 3s;
  -moz-animation: fadein 3s;
  /* Firefox */
  -webkit-animation: fadein 3s;
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-animation: fadein 3s;
  /* Opera */
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.fade-out {
  animation: fadeout 3s;
  -moz-animation: fadeout 3s;
  /* Firefox */
  -webkit-animation: fadeout 3s;
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-animation: fadeout 3s;
  /* Opera */
}

@keyframes fadeout {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
.reply {
  margin: 20px 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: azure;
  font-family: "Architects Daughter";
  position: relative;
}
  .reply:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  }

@media (max-width: 1024px) {
    main .questionnaire .start-test {
      float: none;
    }
    main .questionnaire .start-test,
  main .questionnaire .next, main .questionnaire .previous {
      display: block;
      margin: 35px auto;
    }
    .padding{
      padding: 50%;
    }
    #count-reply{
    margin-top: 3%;
    }
  }
  @media (max-width: 725px) {
    main .questionnaire .next, main .questionnaire .previous {
      float: none;
    }
  }
  @media (max-width: 600px) {
    main {
      width: 90%;
    }
    main .questionnaire h1 {
      font-size: 3.5em;
    }
    main .questionnaire .information > div,
    #count-reply{
      font-size: 1.75em;
    }
    #count-reply{
    margin-top: 5%;
    padding-bottom: 1.5%;
    }
  }

.danger,
.danger:hover {
  background: #dc3545;
}

.check,
.check:hover {
  background: #28a745;
}

.danger:after,
.check:after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 2%;
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro";
  font-weight: 900;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.danger:after {
  content: "";
}

.check:after {
  content: "";
}

.results {
  margin-top: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
.results button {
  display: block;
  margin: 15px auto;
}

#result {
  margin-top: 50px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: white;
  font-family: "Architects Daughter";
  padding: 10px;
}

#yes, #no {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 7px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

#yes:hover, #no:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

#loading {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px dotted;
  border-bottom-color: black;
  border-top-color: black;
  border-right-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 45%;
  animation: loading 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes loading {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  40% {
    transform: rotate(-80deg);
  }
  90% {
    transform: rotate(20deg);
    border-left-color: black;
  }
}

video{
position: fixed;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
display: block;
}

.swal2-popup {
  font-size: 1.6rem !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <title>¿Cuánto sabes sobre el Universo?</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/8.0.1/normalize.css"/>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Andika+New+Basic&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Electrolize&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Architects+Daughter&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@sweetalert2/theme-dark@4/dark.css">
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10/dist/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <video autoplay loop playsinline muted poster="https://i.ibb.co/mF19K2j/universo.jpg">
        
    <source src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/iu1bceauye8jhbx/found-video-3.mp4?dl=1" type="video/mp4">   
        
    </video>
    <main>
      <div class="questionnaire">
        <section class="information">
          <h1>¿Cuánto sabes sobre el Universo?</h1>
          <div><b style="text-transform:uppercase;font-style:italic;">¿Qué es el universo?</b> El universo es la totalidad del espacio y del tiempo, de todas las formas de la materia, la energía, el impulso, las leyes y constantes físicas que las gobiernan. Sin embargo, el término también se utiliza en sentidos contextuales ligeramente diferentes y alude a conceptos como cosmos, mundo o naturaleza.​<br/><br/> Su estudio, en las mayores escalas, es el objeto de la cosmología, disciplina basada en la astronomía y la física, en la cual se describen todos los aspectos de este universo con sus fenómenos.<br/><br/>La ciencia modeliza el universo como un sistema cerrado que contiene energía y materia adscritas al espacio-tiempo y que se rige fundamentalmente por principios causales.<br/><br/> Basándose en observaciones del universo observable, los físicos intentan describir el continuo espacio-tiempo en el que nos encontramos, junto con toda la materia y energía existentes en él. <b>¿Te animas a responder este formulario sobre Cuánto sabes acerca del Universo?</b></div>
          <button class="start-test">Empezar test</button>
        </section>
      </div>
    </main> 
    <audio id="sound-background" controls loop autoplay hidden>
    <source type="audio/mp3" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/46n85r0dtup3gpo/sound-found-universe.mp3?dl=1">
    </audio>
  </body>
</html>
```

***PREGUNTA EDITADA.***

Hola, bueno estaba terminando este cuestionario, y tengo un pequeño, al dar clic en una respuesta, me agrega la clase `check` cuando es correcta y cuando no lo es, la clase `danger` , el problema es que cuando hago click en el boton <> , me quita las clases, necesito seguir mostrandolas, asi con todas las respuestas siguientes, me debe seguir mostrando esas clases siempre que se haya clickeado en una respuesta y luego en el Boton Anterior.

Nose si esto se deba a la funcion `addNewText(title, answers)` , donde al parametro answers, le paso como valor el div hijo de la clase information `<section class="information"><div></div></section>` y a su innerHTML agrego 4 divs con clases ya establecidas `.reply y r1 - r3`. ¿Cómo arreglar esto? , me ha dado problemas de cabeza, Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Trata de guardarlo en un array.

```
const preguntas = [
    "¿Cuánto es el diámetro del Universo?",
    "¿Qué es una protogalaxia?",
    "¿Cuántas y cuáles son los tipos de galaxia"
];

const respuestasCorrectas = [
    "a)", // Respuesta de la pregunta 1
    "b)", // Respuesta de la pregunta 2
    "c)" // Respuesta de la pregunta 3
];

const respuestas = {
    0: [
        "a) Any",
        "b) Any",
        "c) Any",
    ],
    1: [
        "a) Any",
        "b) Any",
        "c) Any",
    ],
    2: [
        "a) Any",
        "b) Any",
        "c) Any",
    ],
};

var current = 0; // La pregunta actual
var respuestaSeleccionada = null;

const cargarPregunta = () => {
    root.innerHTML = `
<div id="respuesta">
<h2>${preguntas[current]}</h2>
<div class="cont">
${respuestas[Object.keys(respuestas)[current]][0]}
</div>
<div class="cont">
${respuestas[Object.keys(respuestas)[current]][1]}
</div>
<div class="cont">
${respuestas[Object.keys(respuestas)[current]][2]}
</div>
</div>
`;
    document.querySelectorAll(".cont").forEach(el => {
        el.addEventListener("click", () => {
            if (respuestaSeleccionada == null) {
                respuestaSeleccionada = el;
                el.style.background = "#a9ffa1";
            } else {
                respuestaSeleccionada.removeAttribute("style");
                respuestaSeleccionada = el;
                el.style.background = "#a9ffa1";
            }
        });
    });
};

cargarPregunta();

enviarRespuesta.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (typeof respuestaSeleccionada == "object" && respuestaSeleccionada !== null) {
        if (respuestaSeleccionada.innerText.includes(respuestasCorrectas[current])) {
            if (current >= preguntas.length - 1) {
                root.parentNode.innerHTML = "<h2>Has completado el quiz</h2>";
            } else {
                current++;
                cargarPregunta();
            }
        } else {
            err.style.opacity = "1";
            err.innerHTML = "Respuesta no correcta";
            setTimeout(() => {
                err.style.opacity = "0";
            }, 1200);
        }
    } else {
        err.style.opacity = "1";
        err.innerHTML = "Selecciona una respuesta";
        setTimeout(() => {
            err.style.opacity = "0";
        }, 1200);
    }
});
```

Tu estructura HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
       <div class="center">
            <div id="root"></div>
            <p><button class="btnExp" id="enviarRespuesta">Enviar</button></p>
            <p style="text-align: left; color: red;" id="err"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body,
html {
    font-family: Arial;
}

.cont {
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: -2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s;
    -o-transition: 0.3s;
}

.center {
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

button {
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 12px;
    background: dodgerblue;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

[Míralo en CodePen](https://codepen.io/coding123inc/pen/poEdyzR)

### Edit

He tratado de acoplar el código en tu caso

**HTML**

```html
<!-- Añade Font Awesome -->
<div class="center">
  <div id="root">
  </div>
  <button class="btn-blue" id="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
body, html {
  font-family:apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI","Roboto","Oxygen","Ubuntu","Cantarell","Fira Sans","Droid Sans","Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;
}

.center {
  width:65%;
  text-align:center;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  -moz-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  -o-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  position:absolute;
}

.cont {
  padding:1rem;
  margin-top:12px;
  border-radius:8px;
  border:solid 1px #c6c6c6c1;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.btn-blue {
    padding: .7em 1.4em;
    margin-top:12px;
    border-radius: .15em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    outline:none;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #3369ff;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -0.6em 0 -0.35em rgba(0,0,0,.17);
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    border: none;
}

.btn-blue:active {
    top: .1em;
}

.fa-check {
  margin-left:-2rem;
  margin-top:3px;
  position:absolute;
  color:#4ddb4f;
}

.fa-times {
  margin-left:-2rem;
  margin-top:3px;
  position:absolute;
  color:#ff5e5e;
}
```

**JS**

```javascript
const preguntas = [
    "P 1",
    "P 2",
    "P 3",
];

const respuestas = {
    0: [
        "a) Any",
        "b) Any",
        "c) Any",
    ],
    1: [
        "a) Any",
        "b) Any",
        "c) Any",
    ],
    2: [
        "a) Any",
        "b) Any",
        "c) Any",
    ],
};

const correctas = [
    "a)",
    "b)",
    "c)",
];

let current = 0;
let score = 0;
let selected = null;
let scorePerCAns = 3; // Puntaje a añadir por cada pregunta correcta 

// ---------------------- //

const cargarPregunta = () => {
    root.innerHTML = "";
    root.innerHTML = `<h2>${preguntas[current]}</h2>`;
    respuestas[Object.keys(respuestas)[current]].forEach(el => {
        root.innerHTML += `
        <div class="cont">
          <span>${el}</span>
        </div>
      `;
    });
    document.querySelectorAll(".cont").forEach(el => {
        el.addEventListener("click", () => {
            if (selected == null) {
                el.innerHTML = "<i class='fas fa-check'></i> " + el.innerHTML;
                selected = el;
            } else {
                selected.innerHTML = selected.innerHTML.replace("<i class='fas fa-check'></i>", "").replace('<i class="fas fa-check"></i>', "");
                el.innerHTML = "<i class='fas fa-check'></i> " + el.innerHTML;
                selected = el;
            }
        });
    })
};

const validarPregunta = () => {
    if (selected.innerText.includes(correctas[current])) {
        score = score + scorePerCAns;
        selected.classList.add("check");
        current++;
        setTimeout(() => {
            cargarPregunta();
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        selected.classList.add("danger");
        selected.classList.remove("check");
        selected.innerHTML = selected.innerHTML.replace("<i class='fas fa-check'></i>", "").replace('<i class="fas fa-check"></i>', "");
        selected.innerHTML = "<i class='fas fa-times'></i> " + selected.innerHTML;
        current++;
        setTimeout(() => {
            cargarPregunta();
        }, 1000);
    }
};

// ---------------------- //

cargarPregunta();

submit.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (current == preguntas.length - 1) {
      validarPregunta();
    root.parentNode.innerHTML = "<h2>Has completado el quiz</h2><p>Score: "+score+"</p>";
  } else {
    validarPregunta();
  }
});
```

[Míralo en CodePen](https://codepen.io/coding123inc/pen/ExgoBYe?editors=0010)

Comment: Ok, ya me has dado una idea de como hacerlo, volvere a escribir un comentario para mostrar mi progreso

Comment: estoy en la fase final de terminar este cuestionario. Aun no puedo resolver el problema de mantener la clase check o danger cuando se hace click en el boton Anterior. Tal vez este boton sea innecesario, pero realmente lo quiero poner para que haya más interacciones. Tal vez esto debe en la linea 79 a 82, al poner innerHTML y crear elementos donde ya establezco sus clases. Por ende al hacer click en Anterior no me seguira mostrando la clase check o danger, ¿Como puedo resolver esto? Cualquier idea me ayudaria

Comment: Edite el código, perdon si me demore mucho en responder, fue algo dificil realizar todo eso :(